# root finding equation with 1 variable integrate

Tags: python

I am new to python. I have looked into scipy modules to find this but unsuccessful. Her is a my problem. I have an equation t is the unknown 0.3 is the initial guess. However I know area is given, c and x is given. I need to find for a given area, c and x(0to1) what is the value of t. I am not sure how to do this? any ideas?

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np

c=1
t=0.3
## x = 0 to 1
def evalfunction(x, c, t): return 5*t*c*(0.2969*float(np.sqrt(x/c))+(-0.1260)*(x/c)+(-0.3516)*(x/c)**2+(0.2843)*(x/c)**3+(-0.1015)*(x/c)**4)
x3 = lambda x:evalfunction(x, c, t)
#x3 = lambda x: 5*t*c*(0.2969*float(np.sqrt(x/c))+(-0.1260)*(x/c)+(-0.3516)*(x/c)**2+(0.2843)*(x/c)**3+(-0.1015)*(x/c)**4)
area = integrate.quad(x3, 0, 1)
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search, i.e. guess an upper and lower bound for `t`, and then minimize the difference of area as gotten by `integrate.quad(x3,0,1)` and your expected `area`. When this difference is at its minimum up to some tolerance that you determine, you have found your `t`.